# How to use a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Im trying to get this struct to print out and I can't figure out what is wrong. 
The code is supposed to do the following:
-Read the first name, last name, ss#, and age from the keyboard and save them in the variable: person.

-Display the last name, the first name, the age, and the ss# from variable: person.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Rec
{
    char firstName [20];
    char lastName [30];
    char ss [12];
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    struct Rec person;
    char personInfo[100]; 
    int i;
    printf("Enter a first name, a space, a last name, a space, a ss#, a space, and an age all on the same line.");
    scanf("%s" , &personInfo); 


    for (i=0, i<100; i++)
    {
        int count=0, z=0;
        if (personInfo[i]= ' ')
            count++;
        else if( count ==0)
        {
            for (z=0; z<100; z++)
            person[z].firstName=personInfo[i]; 
        }
        else if (count ==1) 
        {
            for (z=0; z<100; z++)
            person[z].lastName=personInfo[i]; 
        }
        else if (count ==2)
        {
            for (z=0; z<100; z++)
            person[z].ss=personInfo[i];
        }
        else if (count ==3)
        {
            for (z=0; z<100; z++)
            person[z].age=personInfo[i];
        }
    }


    printf("Name: %s %s, Social Security: %s, Age: %d\n", person[i].firstName, person[i].lastName, personInfo[i].ss, personInfo[i].age);


    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You said you can't figure out what is wrong, but you haven't told us what you think the program should be doing or what it is actually doing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's a request for a debugging slave.

Answer (score 1):

Problems that I see:

**One**

```
scanf("%s" , &personInfo);
```

`scanf` will stop reading when it finds a white space. It will only read the first name.

You need to use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) to retrieve a line of text, including whitespaces.

**Two**

```
        person[z].firstName=personInfo[i];
```

Type of `person[z].firstName` is `char [20]`. Type of `personInfo[i]` is `char`. This is an invalid assignment. Your intent is not clear to me.

**Three**

```
printf("Name: %s %s, Social Security: %s, Age: %d\n", person[i].firstName, person[i].lastName, personInfo[i].ss, personInfo[i].age);
```

At the point this line is executed, value of `i` is `100`. You are accessing `person[100]`, which is beyond the valid memory allocated. It will lead to undefined behavior.

**Suggestion**

If you want to read `100` records and print them one by one, you need two `for` blocks, not one. The first `for` loop iterates over the number of persons. The second `for` loop iterates over the characters of each line read.

```
for (i=0, i<100; i++)
{
    // Read the record of the i-th person.
    fgets(personInfo, 100, stdin);

    for ( int j = 0; j < 100; ++j )
    {
       // Extract the info from the line and fill up the data
       // in person[i]
    }

    // Print the record of the i-th person.
}
```